# Dynamic Arrays in Excel not Spilling

Tags: excel, office365, dynamic-arrays, spill-range

I just bought a new computer and installed Windows 10 and latest version of office 365 Home.
When I use dynamic arrays in Excel there is suddenly no longer any spill which creates issues since I use files with macros that are adapted after the typical behavoir of dynamic arrays.

I can type in a dynamic array and values appear like before. But instead of "spilling" values to neigbouring cells excel instead pastes values into those cells. There is also no longer any gray text in the formula bar and if I delete the original cell which contains the dynamic array formula all other cells remain.

I havent changed any of the files and have tried to reinstall excel without success. I also cant find any other that previously have reported this issue.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Understanding the problem rests on your definition of "dynamic arrays". How would you "type" such an array into a cell? How would your code (presumably VBA???) do that? Please provide examples of both, preferably by adding such detail to your question  .

Comment: So the formula `=SEQUENCE(5,,1,1)` will only appear as a formula in the first cell but static numbers in the last four cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for the quick input. I found out what the issue was thanks to your clarifying questions. The sequence formula turned out to work as expected which excluded that it was an issue with Excel. The formulas I was using was instead related to an excel plugin called "Börsdata". And although I've installed it like before this time the initial settings turned out to be different. After changing the settings to "show data as dynamic array" it now works as expected.